# How can i avoid the `hardcoding` of id in find method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

How can i avoid the `hardcoding` of id here?. Below is the code where i am hardcoding the id 22.

```
it "can find an Project that this user belongs to" do 
    project = Project.find( id: '22', authorization: @auth )        
    hashed_response = FactoryGirl.build(:project_json).marshal_dump.to_json
    expect(project.to_json).to eq(hashed_response);
end
```

Below is the code of complete class.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Project do

  before(:all) do
    @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "123", description: "123");
    @user =  FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com", password: nil, code: nil);
    user = User.login(FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com", 
                               password: "123", code: 0));

      if user
        @auth = user['auth']        
      end
  end

  it "can create an Project" do    
    expect{Project.create(project: @acc, user: @user)}.to 
                      change{Project.all(authorization: @auth).size}.by (1);    
  end

  it "can find an Project that this user belongs to" do 
    project = Project.find( id: '22', authorization: @auth )        
    hashed_response = FactoryGirl.build(:project_json).marshal_dump.to_json
    expect(project.to_json).to eq(hashed_response);
  end

end
```

I was looking at some tutorials http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html, but i don't understand how they are passing.

Comment: like this? `project = Project.find(id: @project.id, authorization: @auth )`

Comment: when i use @project.id, it fetches me all records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Project can belong to a User you can do...

```
project = Project.find_by( user_id: @user.id , authorization: @auth )
```

If the User can belong to a Project then instead you'd do...

```
project = Project.find_by( id: @user.project_id, authorization: @auth )
```

Comment: If the Project can belong to a User you can do, but we need to get the specific project right? How will this fetch.

Comment: If i pass the specific id like 22, 23 of that projects, it returns me... but i just want to avoid this numbers.

Comment: Are you saying you want to retrieve a project not associated with a user?  How do you want to identify which project?

Comment: A user can have multiple projects... I want to find a project provided with a project_id...

Answer (score 1):

And how is the project id provided? With a form? Then it would be `params [:id]` or `params [:project_id]` but in tests it would be @project.id

Comment: I get it... but @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "123", description: "123"); is just a model... how would this have an id?

Comment: @UnderTaker - `FactoryGirl.create(:project` will create a new record in the database so it will have an id - `FactoryGirl.build(:project` will create an in-memory model that will not have an id until saved

Comment: It's a `create`d model so it has been saved to the table in the database and was automatically assigned an id.

Comment: In my application, i am hitting a Rest based API to fetch the project information.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it was helpful in other ways... one question... what is desired way of passing an id to find method when your find method calls a RestFul service to fetch information?.

Comment: You would have a RESTful url like `http://myapp/projects/1` and in your show method you would be able to retrieve the record with `@project = Project.find(params[:id])` because the `1` would be passed in as `params[:id]`